# Create URL to here.com maps Driving Directions with addresses/coordinates passed along

Tags: here-api

Anybody know how to create a proper URL to link to `here.com` maps, from my site? We use an extensive amount of API calls to embed the maps inside our site, but I want to send emails to people with a `'Click Here for directions'` link inside pointing to `here.com` driving directions with the address or coordinates built into the URL.

Example:

With Google Maps, all we would have to do is make a simple link like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=32.5589671,-97.2586011&daddr=32.7787855,-97.4495476
```

Just pass along the variables `saddr` and `daddr` within the URL. I've tried everything to build a proper URL for `here.com` maps and it doesn't process it properly.

My best attempt was:

```
https://www.here.com/directions/drive/32.2589671,-97.4486011/Weatherford,_Texas?x=ep&map=30.38114,-89.89326,6,normal
```

But it does not process this URL properly and now I'm pretty much stuck, since I have tried everything that I know to try.

Answer (score 2):

Something like [https://www.here.com/directions/drive/start:lat1,lng1/end:lat2,lng2](https://www.here.com/directions/drive/start:48.85,2.35/end:52.51,13.38) seems to work.

- The text before the colon provides the text of the start/end location
- There should be absolutely **no** spaces between the latitude and longitude
- If no `map` parameter is added, the map view defaults to show the whole route on a street map
- If a `map` parameter of the form `?map=lat,lng,zoom,maptype` is added, the map initially shows the map view specified, then moves to show the whole route - like this [satellite map link](https://www.here.com/directions/drive/start:48.85,2.35/end:52.51,13.38?map=0,0,1,satellite)

I've checked that the *first* [link](https://www.here.com/directions/drive/start:48.85,2.35/end:52.51,13.38) (without the `map` parameter) also works on a Windows Phone to forward to the HERE Maps app if it is installed. I've not tested what happens if the [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.here.app.maps) or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/here-maps/id577430143) HERE Maps apps are installed on mobile. If the HERE Maps app is not present on a mobile, the site should forward to the **m.here.com** [mobile friendly site](http://m.here.com/#action=route&params=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22sname%22%3A%22Paris%22%2C%22slat%22%3A48.85693%2C%22slng%22%3A2.3412%2C%22sPlaceId%22%3A%22250u09tv-f5542e10a8944d85829c7663703fa5ed%22%2C%22ename%22%3A%22Berlin%22%2C%22elat%22%3A52.51607%2C%22elng%22%3A13.37698%2C%22ePlaceId%22%3A%22276u33db-fbcffd2e52f94f56b6f554c0baa33f06%22%7D&bmk=1).

Other endpoints will vary by device - the following are fine on tablets:

- [Parisian Restaurants](https://www.here.com/discover/restaurant?map=48.85,2.35,15,normal) `https://www.here.com/discover/restaurant?map=48.85,2.35,15,normal`
- [New York Traffic](https://www.here.com/traffic/explore?map=40.7127,-74,15,normal) `https://www.here.com/traffic/explore?map=40.7127,-74,15,normal`