# Open here map url from mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone, here-api

I'm developing hybrid application and want to access to HERE map url from any device (android / ios / windows phone / web)

I tried to follow this answer : [Create URL to here.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27805690/1381820)

But It's not working in all cases.

In my case, i tried this url : https://www.here.com/directions/drive/start:48.85,2.35/end:52.51,13.38

- Android without Here map app installed : open m.here.com -> **ok**
- Android with Here map installed : open m.here.com but do not find app installed -> **failed**
- iOS without Here map app installed : open m.here.com -> **ok**
- iOS with Here map app installed : open m.here.com and ask if we want to use app installed, but if i click yes, app say me 'cannot find itinerary' -> **failed**
- Windows Phone 10 without Here map app installed : ask me to install Here map app, if i say yes, redirect to store with no result (failed), if i say no, error page -> **failed**
- Windows Phone 10 with Here map app installed : open app but say me 'cannot find itinerary' -> **failed**
- Web : **ok**

I have more errors than success cases, so i can't use this kind of url.

Is there a different kind of URL that I can use to open `m.here.com` if there is no installed application, and launch application if it is installed?
(or open `m.here.com` in all cases at least)

Answer (score 1):

The deeplinking developer guide has been recently made public, you could use that.

- https://github.com/heremaps/map-linkbuilder-app
- http://heremaps.github.io/map-linkbuilder-app/

So, try creating share urls

(You'll get something like this: https://share.here.com/r/52.51607,13.37699,Berlin%2C%20Germany/51.05364,13.74082,Dresden%2C%20Saxony%2C%20Germany?m=d&t=normal)